# Hide first modal behind overlay if second modal is opened

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, overlay

I have a modal that contains a button which triggers second modal. The problem is the second modal's overlay is not hiding first .It only make the background more darker How can i do make second modals overlay hide first modal?

[image]

Code

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>Modal Example</h3>
    <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
    <div> <a href="#myModal1" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch Modal</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal1" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3>First Modal</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"> <a href="#myModal2" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch Second Modal</a>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="myModal2" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3>Second Modal</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body"></div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/2/

Comment: Duplicated: please ref. https://stackoverflow.com/q/19305821/3845970

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have this jquery solution. If someone has any css solution pls suggest me

```
$('#myModal2').on('show.bs.modal', function() {  
    $('.modal').not(this).addClass('opac');
});

$('#myModal2').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
     $('.modal').not(this).removeClass('opac');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/5/

Answer (score 0):

You should differentiate the fist backdrop from the second, so the z-index of the first is lower than the first modal and the z-index of the second backdrop is higher than the first modal but lower than the second.

Comment: I don't thing bootstrap assign a class or anything to differentiate overlay is of particular modal. It just assigns `modal-backdrop in`

Answer (score -1):

You can simply hide the first modal when opening the second one.

Here is the modified jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/patrickhaede/h3WDq/4/

```
<a href="#myModal2" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal">Launch Second Modal</a>
```

Is that what you meant?

Comment: Dont want to hide the modal