# Stacking modals scrolls the main page when one is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

With Bootstrap 3.3.1, I was able to get stacking modals without any additional scripts (as in copy-pasting the modal templates in the Bootstrap site and making many of them in the same page). The problem was that whenever the top (highest) modal is closed, scrolling focus goes to the main page (under all remaining modals) and goes back to the top modal only if a new modal is opened. Is there a way to set the scrolling focus to the next modal and not the main page?

When I tested the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21816777/4339908) (and even [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24914782/4339908)) by adding text to the `body` and individual `modals` (through Firefox's "Edit as HTML" to test scrolling) and it had the characteristics that I needed.

A problem that occurred when I tried it with the latest jQuery and Bootstrap was that the `modal-backdrop` then shows above the `modal-dialog`. Upon *Inspect Element* whenever one or more modals are up, I noticed that the `div` for the `modal-backdrop` appears within the main `div` of the `modal`:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg"></div>
</div>
```

as compared to the bottom of `body` like it is [here](http://miles-by-motorcycle.com/static/bootstrap-modal/index.html). This even happens when I use 3.3.1 on that linked example. I think this resulted in the main `div` and `modal-backdrop` having the modified `z-index`, but not the `modal-dialog`, so I tried to fix it by adding a line to set the `modal-dialog` to have its parent's `z-index` plus 1. It put the backdrops in their proper place, but the scrolling problem persists. Is this because of a change in 3.3.1 or was I looking at the wrong solution?

Comment: It seems that you only have to add `data-backdrop="false"` to your nested modals, see: http://jsfiddle.net/u038t9L0/

Comment: Backdrop's not the problem (fixed that in the last paragraph of the question). Not being able to scroll through shown modals if the top one is closed is.

Add long content you'd have to scroll through in the body along with each of the modals in jsfiddle. Open each of the modals, you'll notice you can scroll up and down. Close one and you'll notice that the modal/s still up don't scroll but the content in the body (that's not in any modal) does.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

> Backdrop's not the problem. Not being able to scroll through shown modals if the top one is closed is.

You should add the following Javascript:

```js
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    // For Bootstrap 4:
    // if ($('.modal').hasClass('show')) {
    if ($('.modal').hasClass('in')) {
        $('body').addClass('modal-open');
    }    
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/u038t9L0/1/

When the body has class `modal-open` the following CSS will be applied for your `.modals`:

```
.modal-open .modal {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Closing the modal will remove the `modal-open` class from the modal too.

Comment: Working with angular, modals appears dinamically on the body. For this reason, it is neccesary to change the selector to `$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function (e) {}`. This will work with modals inside templates

Comment: For Bootstrap 4, use the 2nd line `if($('.modal').hasClass('show')) {` instead