# Bootstrap Modal Issue - Scrolling Gets Disabled

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal and within that modal, there is a dropdown that displays large hidden content, which is working.

Now when you open the next modal, stacked on top of the first modal and dismiss it, the scrolling on modal underneath becomes disabled.

I have created a full example, including the steps to replicate the issue I am facing. You can see it [here](http://lazybots.com/modal_error.php).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title></title>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>


    <input type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_1" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" value="Open Modal 1" >

    <div class="modal fade" id="modal_1">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">First Modal</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">



                    <form class="form">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>1) Open This First: </label>
                            <input type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_2" class="btn btn-primary" value="Open Modal 2" >
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>2) Change this once you have opened the modal above.</label>
                            <select id="change" class="form-control">
                                <option value="small">Show Small Content</option>
                                <option value="large">Show Large Content</option>
                            </select>
                        </div> 

                        <div id="large" class='content-div'>
                            <label>Large Textarea Content.. Try and scroll to the bottom..</label>
                            <textarea rows="30" class="form-control"></textarea>

                        </div>

                        <div id="small" class='content-div'>
                            <label> Example Text Box</label> 
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>  


                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="modal fade" id="modal_2">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Second Modal</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <hp>This is the stacked modal.. Close this modal, then chenge the dropdown menu, you cannot scroll... </h5>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {


        $(".content-div").hide();
        $("#change").change(function() {
            $(".content-div").hide();
            $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
        });


    });

</script>
</html>
```

Here's a Bootply to show the behaviour in action:

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/GBbtwkQMTf)

Comment: ["Be sure not to open a modal while another is still visible. Showing more than one modal at a time requires custom code"](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), and also violates the purpose for which modals were intended.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/24914782/58241 which contains a fix not only for the scrollbar issue but for styling issues as well

Answer (score 178):

This is also a solution

```
.modal {
  overflow-y:auto;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/LZBqdq2jl5

Auto works fine :) This will actually fix any modal that runs higher than your screen size.

Comment: This solution solved my problem, while closing and opening modals from jQuery `$('.modal').css('overflow-y', 'auto');`

Answer (score 97):

This is because when you close a modal, it removes the `modal-open` from the `<body>` tag. Bootstrap doesn't support multiple modals on the same page (At least until BS3).

One way to make it work, is to use the `hidden.bs.modal` event triggered by BS when closing a modal, then check if there is anyother modal open in order to force the `modal-open` class on the body.

```
// Hack to enable multiple modals by making sure the .modal-open class
// is set to the <body> when there is at least one modal open left
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    if($('.modal.in').length > 0)
    {
        $('body').addClass('modal-open');
    }
});
```

Comment: (BS4) First answer I could get to work, just had to use ($('.modal.show').length > 0) for Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Thanks - my issue wasn't quite the same but your comment pointed me to the modal-open class on body which is the cause of the lost page scroll action.

Comment: the best answer

Comment: This is accually The BEST answer i ever found in stack overflow .

Comment: Very nice! I just added this to my app.js (BS5) and it works beautifully.

Answer (score 51):

I have found a solution for you. I'm not sure why it doesn't work but just one line code in your CSS will solve the problem. After closing second modal, the first one are getting `overflow-y:hidden` somehow. Even if its set to `auto` actually.

You need to rewrite this and set your own declaration in CSS:

```
#modal_1 {
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Here you have a working [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/567JXNi3kB)

**Edit**: wrong link, sorry.

Comment: not working, it makes container scrollable but makes mouse wheel stucked also

Answer (score 26):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 $('.modal').on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) { //fire on closing modal box
        if ($('.modal:visible').length) { // check whether parent modal is opend after child modal close
            $('body').addClass('modal-open'); // if open mean length is 1 then add a bootstrap css class to body of the page
        }
    });
});
//this code segment will activate parent modal dialog 
//after child modal box close then scroll problem will automatically fixed
```

Comment: IMO this is best answer. Adding the extra css for overflow-y: auto works too but as mentioned below, results in double scrollbars.

Comment: Works with Bootstrap 4.1 too. Appreciated

Comment: Agreed. tested 2-3 answers and this one works for Twitter Bootstrap 4.2.1.

Answer (score 18):

For bootstrap 4 I had to add !Important

```
.modal {
    overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

If this is not done, it does not work and it is not applied.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: For me it is an half working solution, because i need to click on the modal te re-gain scroll ability. The @ashish dwivedi  solution worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 15):

Follow https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog/issues/70 add

```
.modal { overflow: auto !important; }
```

to your css

Comment: this solution would create two scrollbars

Comment: there are so many solution here that they said is working, i picked this one because of simplicity. worked perfectly for me. upvoted.

Answer (score 14):

Bootstrap did not support multiple modals at the same time. It is a Bootstrap Bug. Just add the below script for BS4.

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
if($('.modal.show').length > 0)
{
    $('body').addClass('modal-open');
}
});
```

Comment: Works great. But be sure to put this code after your modals, or in a `$(document).ready` method.

Answer (score 10):

```
$('.modal').css('overflow-y', 'auto');
```

Answer (score 7):

First off, multiple open modals are not supported by Bootstrap. See here: [Bootstrap Modal docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

> Multiple open modals not supported.
>   Be sure not to open a modal while another is still visible. Showing more than one modal at a time requires custom code.

But, if you must, you can add this bit of CSS in your custom stylesheet, as long as it's included ***after*** the main Bootstrap stylesheet:

```
.modal {
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue by removing `data-dismiss="modal"`
and adding

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('#myModal2').modal('show') }, 500);
$('#myModal1').modal('hide');
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @Sunny I don't know why other solutions are not worked for me but this one is definitely worked

Comment: @MasihAkbari it could be version issue :) This one is also help me. I'm using BS4. It might have a little performance issue due to delay, but this is quick easy fix.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is because of a bug in twitter bootstrap.  It seems to remove the `modal-open` class from the body even if two modals were open.  You can shoe in a test for jQuery's `removeClass` function and bypass it if there's a modal still open (credit for the base function goes to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1950199/854246).

```
(function(){
    var originalRemoveClassMethod = jQuery.fn.removeClass;

    jQuery.fn.removeClass = function(){
        if (arguments[0] === 'modal-open' && jQuery('.modal.in').length > 1) {
            return this;
        }
        var result = originalRemoveClassMethod.apply( this, arguments );
        return result;
    }
})();
```

Comment: As mentioned by @Blazemonger, [Bootstrap explicitly doesn't support stacking modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Answer (score 1):

This codes solved mine,when second popup closed, my first popup can't scroll any more.

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '#SecondModal', function (e) {
  if ($('#FirstModal').is(':visible')) { // check if first modal open 
    $('body').addClass('modal-open'); // re-add class 'modal-open' to the body because it was removed when we close the second modal
    $('#FirstModal').focus(); // Focus first modal to activate scrollbar
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a hack , but I like to just close and reopen it upon modal close to do away with any weird/unwanted behavior. If you have fade turned off then you cannot notice it closing and reopening:

```
var $ModalThatWasOnTop= $('#ModalThatWasOnTop')

$ModalThatWasOnTop.on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
     console.log('closing  modal that was on top of the other modal')
     $('#ModalThatWasCovered').modal('hide');
     $('#ModalThatWasCovered').modal('show');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting this inside component code which you are trying to open in modal is working for me. Have a look.

```
 host: {
    '[style.display]': '"flex"',
    '[style.flex-direction]': '"column"',
    '[style.overflow]': '"auto"'
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> It's Easy

```
.modal { overflow-y: auto !important; }
```

Comment: It's easy because you copied from [others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54196631/6670491)? When answering old question, please read existing answer before posting yours.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I'm just advising you to check for existing answer (especially on an old question 6+ years old) before posting your (duplicated) version instead of wasting your time. This kind of answers usually end up being Flagged and removed.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled on this problem with bootstrap 5. Since bootstrap 5 is walking away from jQuery, here is a solution when you open multiple modals and your body element scrolling gets disabled. Events can be found here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#events;

```js
 document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', (event) => {
    // remove the overflow: hidden and padding-right: 15px
    document.querySelector('body').removeAttribute('style');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are opening another Modal from one Modal you can use this:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    // Load up a new modal...   
    $('#myModalNew').modal('show') 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add via JQuery the class 'modal-open' to the body. I presume that the scroll works on everything except the modal.

As a comment to the previous responses : adding the overflow property to the modal ( via CSS ) helps but then you will have two scroll bars in the page .

Answer (score 0):

This is also a solution

```
.modal.fade .modal-dialog{
   -webkit-transform: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have actually figured out a solution for this. You actually need to enable the scrolling for your page body if you are using `$('#myModal').hide();` to hide a model. Just write the following line after `$('#myModal').hide();`:

```
$('body').attr("style", "overflow:auto")
```

This will re-enable the scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap3 or 4, make sure you have a class modal-open in html body.
I am not sure if this is mandatory, but maybe make sure your z-index of modal-backdrop is cleared.

```
    $('.your-second-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('.your-second-modal').css('z-index', "");
        $('.modal-backdrop').css('z-index', 1040);
        $('body').addClass("modal-open");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this below js code

```
    $(document).on("click",".modal",function () {
       if(!$("body").hasClass('modal-open'))
           $("body").addClass('modal-open');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS code its work for me.

```
.modal.fade.in {
        transform: translateZ(0);
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Angular +2 enviroment in style.scss use following class it works like magic

```
  .cdk-overlay-container .cdk-global-overlay-wrapper {
    pointer-events: auto !important;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens, because after closing second modal, first modal
`id="modal_1"` lost css attribute: `overflowY:auto`.

You need to restore that and it will works. For instance in your code example simple add:

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '#modal_2',function () {
       $('#modal_1').css('overflowY','auto')
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple if you using bootstrap modal than you need to remove tabindex="-1"
**in place of this**

**Paste**