# fancy-box sub-box losing overlay when returning to main box

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

I have a fancy-box with some buttons in it, when you click a button, it opens a new fancy-box, when you close that box it returns you to the original. however, when it returns to the original, the overlay dissappears! **How can I prevent this from happening?** *I am using fancybox 1.3.4*

Here is a sample which demonstrates the issue:

**HTML**

```
<div style=display:none>
    <div id=modal1>
        Modal 1<br />
        <input type=button href=#modal2 value=modal2 />
    </div>
    <div id=modal2>
        modal 2
    </div>
</div>
<input type=button href=#modal1 value=modal1 />
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('input[href=#modal1]').fancybox();
    $('input[href=#modal2]').fancybox({
        onClosed:function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
        $.fancybox({href:'#modal1'});
    },0);
    }
    });
});
```

fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/e27mgovv/
(Click modal1 button, then modal2 button, then close modal2)

Comment: The second modal is clearly destroying the overlay, however your required behaviour is unusual - triggering a modal from inside a modal, I would rather think of updating the content of the modal itself

Comment: hmm, I suppose I could update the content by just shoving all the "sub-modals" into a single modal, and using jquery to toggle the divs, that seems like it would work

Comment: I'd do that - most modal plugins I've seen, check for the existence of the overlay before creating it - so you don't end up with multiple ones. The same way, they just remove the overlay when one modal is closed.

Comment: I think you should take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305821/bootstrap-3-0-multiple-modals-overlay Maybe something similar can be done with fancy-box?

Comment: @Luca when I close the sub modal, then it seems like it should close the overlay, and re-opening the top level modal should turn the overlay back on, perhaps because i am sort of "replacing" the main modal with the sub modal, the overlay gets lost, im going to try manually closing the main modal before triggering the sub

Comment: Well, this isn't exactly ideal, but I just created my own basic overlay, and control it via the start and close methods: http://jsfiddle.net/e27mgovv/38/

Comment: @Chad that looks great, I'll definitely consider that if I can't get it to work with its own overlay

Comment: @Luca my closing re-opening plan did not work, it never reopened the main modal. I used your initial suggestion of updating the content, but putting all the sub modals in the one fancybox, and toggling the display of each as needed. thanks!

Comment: Try increasing the time interval in the `setTimeout()` function ... I would say to `300`

Comment: @JFK that seems to work too!

Comment: be careful when depending on a timeout, things could still be out of sync - callbacks or promises are a way more robust option!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is the explanation of what is going on :

When you close fancybox, the overlay changes its CSS settings from `display:block` to `display:none`. This is triggered within the fancybox script by `overlay.hide()` when fancybox is closed.

**NOTE**: `overlay.hide()` is always triggered if you use an `onClosed` callback.

When you open a new fancybox within the `onClosed` callback, `overlay.hide()` is triggered but it doesn't seem to have time to change back to `display:block` with the new box, and this why you have to use the `setTimeout()` workaround.

However, bear in mind that if you open a new fancybox from a button (bound to fancybox) inside an opened fancybox (or navigating from one item to another in a fancybox gallery), fancybox will consider this as a *transition* and the `overlay.hide()` method will never be triggered. This is why the overlay remains visible when you *click* the `href="#modal2"` *button* inside of it.

If you don't want to use the `setTimeout()` workaround, mainly because the *overlay* flicks (closes/opens), you may `.off()` the fancybox *close button* and *trigger* a `click` on the `href="#modal1"` *button* to open the first fancybox back as a transition instead of `onClosed`. This way, the `overlay.hide()` method won't be triggered and the overlay will remain visible with smoother transition.

**NOTE** : this method will require to `bind` the fancybox *close button* back to its original functionality within the `onComplete` callback of the `href="#modal1"` initialization script like :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[href=#modal1]').fancybox({
        onComplete: function () {
            $("#fancybox-close").off().on("click", function (event) {
                $.fancybox.close();
            })
        }
    });
    $('input[href=#modal2]').fancybox({
        onComplete: function () {
            $("#fancybox-close").off().on("click", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('input[href=#modal1]').trigger("click");
            })
        }
    });
});
```

See your tweaked **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e27mgovv/39/)**

**NOTES** :

- `.on()` and `.off()` methods require jQuery v1.7+.
- This solution is for fancybox v1.3.4.
- If using `inline` content in fancybox v1.3.4, beware of this **[BUG](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fancybox/-re22BoXOzM)** and workaround