# React-Bootstrap Multiple Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I am using React-bootstrap in my project.
I need to open multiple dialog.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Note:
There is answers for bootstrap [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305821/multiple-modals-overlay) but it does not work in react-bootstrap.
Thanks.

Comment: Multiple dialogs are not supported in bootstrap. Lots of custom work is required to support this feature. Please provide a code example of what you have tried and you will probably receive better answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we just handled multiple modals by having each pass in a different id and then setting the 'show' state to that:

https://github.com/AgileVentures/agile-ventures-website-react-front-end/blob/4_homepage_changes_mob/src/App.js#L26

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      show: null
    };
  }

  handleClose() {
    this.setState({show: id});
  }

  handleShow(id) {
    this.setState({show: id});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <Grid>
          <Row>
            <Col xsOffset={1} sm={5}>
              <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large" onClick={() => this.handleShow('here')}>
                <h1>You are here!</h1>
              </Button>
              <Modal
                show={this.state.show == 'here'} onHide={this.handleClose}
              >
                <Modal.Header closeButton closeLabel="close window">
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                  <p className='landing-page-markers you-are-here'>Tired of toy projects, tutorials and online courses?
                      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                  </p>
                </Modal.Body>
              </Modal>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          ... more modals passing in different ids ...
```

Answer (score 17):

If you are using scss as css preprocessor, then you can use a loop for defining the proper `z-index` 's in order to make everything appears as one top of other.

This loop handles upto 5 levels, you can increase the number if you want

```
@for $i from 1 through 6 {
  $zIndexBackdrop:  #{1000 + (5 * $i)};
  $zIndexContent:  #{1000 + (5 * $i) + 2};
  .modal-backdrop.show:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
    z-index: $zIndexBackdrop;
  }
  div[role="dialog"][aria-modal="true"]:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
    z-index: $zIndexContent;
  }
}
```

The loop here `1 through 6` loops 5 times, you can increase the depth of modals if you want by increase the number.

I have used generic class names used by `react-bootstrap` modals, please do a cross check on how backdrops and main modals are being created.

Answer (score 7):

The "nth-of-type" solution is not working for me.
Instead, I solved it with "nth-last-child" like these.

```
div[role="dialog"][aria-modal="true"]:nth-last-child(1) {
  z-index: 1125;
}
.modal-backdrop.show:nth-last-child(2){
  z-index: 1100;
}
div[role="dialog"][aria-modal="true"]:nth-last-child(3) {
  z-index: 1075;
}
.modal-backdrop.show:nth-last-child(4){
  z-index: 1050;
}
div[role="dialog"][aria-modal="true"]:nth-last-child(5) {
  z-index: 1025;
}
.modal-backdrop.show:nth-last-child(6){
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

The idea is that every time a modal is shown, a modal element and a shadow element will be appended to the body (this happens already by the library). So from the last child, the (n + 1) element will be a modal and the (n + 2) element will be modal shadow element.

In the example, I set the nested modals to be working at  most 3 levels but you can add two of these style as deep as you want.

Comment: This is a clean solution for me. I just need to add those to the CSS file.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using React 16.8+, you can use the React Hook `useState` (and functional component) so you can specify which modals you want it to appear based on the state:

```
export const MyModals = () => {
const [modalState, setModalState] = useState< "modal-one" | "modal-two" | "close" >("close")

const handleShowModalOne = () => {
 setModalState("modal-one")
}

const handleShowModalTwo = () => {
 setModalState("modal-two")
}

const handleClose = () => {
 setModalState("close")
}

return (
 <div>
   <Button onClick={handleShowModalOne}>Show Modal One</Button>

   <Modal show={modalState === "modal-one"}>
     <Modal.Body>This is Modal One</Modal.Body>
     <Modal.Footer>
       <Button onClick={handleShowModalTwo}>Show Modal Two</Button>
     </Modal.Footer>
   </Modal>

   <Modal show={modalState === "modal-two"}>
     <Modal.Body>This is Modal Two</Modal.Body>
     <Modal.Footer>
       <Button onClick={handleClose}>Close</Button>
     </Modal.Footer>
   </Modal>
 </div>
)
}
```

Comment: There's an error  Uncaught TypeError: number 1 is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Answer (score 2):

i used multiple models like this

```
render() {
    return(
       <div>
           <button onClick={() => this.setState({ showModal1:true, showModal2:false});} >open modal one</button>

          <button onClick={() => this.setState({ showModal2:true, showModal1:false});} >open modal two</button>

          <Modal show={this.state.showModal1} onHide={() => this.setState({ showModal1:false});}>
           modal one content..
          </Modal>

          <Modal show={this.state.showModal2} onHide={() => this.setState({ showModal2:false});}>
          modal two content..
       </Modal>

     </div>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what do you want to achieve. I have multiple react bootstrap modal dialogs and also have embedded dialogs, like modal dialog shows popup with error message.
Generally you can define state variable, like this:

```
this.state = {showModal1:true, showModal2:false,...}
```

In your render function you can do like this:

```
render() {
    return(
       <div>
           <Modal show={this.state.showModal1}>
              some modal 1 text comes here
           </Modal>
           <Modal show={this.state.showModal2}>
              some modal 2 text comes here
           </Modal>
       </div>
     );
}
```

In the code above, if both showModal1 and showModal2 are true, you will get both modal dialogs and the second will above the first one.

Comment: is there any way to nest another Modal inside one Modal and if so can you provide an example ?

Comment: Have no simple example, but I did it with react-bootstrap modal component

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import ModalBody from "react-bootstrap/ModalBody";
import ModalFooter from "react-bootstrap/ModalFooter";

const MyModals = () => {
      const [modalState, setModalState] = useState("close");
      
      const handleShowModalOne = () => {
       setModalState("modal-one")
      }
      
      const handleShowModalTwo = () => {
       setModalState("modal-two")
      }
      
      const handleClose = () => {
       setModalState("close")
      }
      
      return (
       <>
       <Modal show={modalState === "modal-one"}>
           <ModalBody>This is Modal One</ModalBody>
           <ModalFooter>
             <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>Close</Button>
             <Button>Save Changes</Button>
           </ModalFooter>
         </Modal>
      
         <Modal show={modalState === "modal-two"}>
           <ModalBody>This is Modal Two</ModalBody>
           <ModalFooter>
             <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>Close</Button>
             <Button>Save Changes</Button>
           </ModalFooter>
         </Modal>

         <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShowModalOne}>Open Model</Button>
         <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShowModalTwo}>Open Second Model</Button></>
      )
   }

   export default MyModals;
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get these 3 react-bootstrap modals working. It is a meet the team component with 3 modals: Marcos, Gonza, and Eliana

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './../css/Wrapper.scss'

function About() {
  
  const [marcosModal, setMarcosModal] = useState(false);
  const [gonzaModal, setGonzaModal] = useState(false);
  const [elianaModal, setElianaModal] = useState(false);
  const handleMarcosClose = () => setMarcosModal(false);
  const handleMarcosShow = () => setMarcosModal(true);
  const handleGonzaClose = () => setGonzaModal(false);
  const handleGonzaShow = () => setGonzaModal(true);
  const handleElianaClose = () => setElianaModal(false);
  const handleElianaShow = () => setElianaModal(true);

  return (
    <div
      className="wrapper"
    >
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <div className="col-12 col-xl-8 offset-xl-2">
            <Container>
              <Row>
                <div
                  className='col-12 col-md-4 pt-5 px-5'>
                  <h2 className='text-center pt-4'>Marcos</h2>
                  <p className='text-center'>Marcos is a founder and instructor at Scuba Point, he has 17 years of diving experience and loves the underwater world.</p>
                  <span className="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg mx-auto w-100 d-block mb-3" onClick={handleMarcosShow}>SEE&nbsp;MORE</span>
                  <Modal
                    keyboard={false}
                    show={marcosModal}
                    onHide={handleMarcosClose}
                  >
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                      <Modal.Title><h2 className='mt-3'>Marcos bio</h2></Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                      Marcos is a diving instructor with 17 years of experience.
                   
                    </Modal.Body>
                  </Modal>
                </div>
                <div
                  className='col-12 col-md-4 pt-5 px-5'>
                  <h2 className='text-center pt-4'>Gonza</h2>
                  <p className='text-center'>Gonza is an Argentinian legend who is passionate about diving, he is excellent at keeping it fun too.</p>
                  <span className="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg mx-auto w-100 d-block mb-3" onClick={handleGonzaShow}>SEE&nbsp;MORE</span>
                  <Modal
                    show={gonzaModal}
                    onHide={handleGonzaClose}
                    keyboard={false}
                  >
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                      <Modal.Title><h2 className='mt-3'>Gonza bio</h2></Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                      Meet Gonza, an experienced and passionate Argentinian diving instructor based in Tenerife.
                      </Modal.Body>
                  </Modal>
                </div>
                <div
                  className='col-12 col-md-4 pt-5 px-5'>
                  <h2 className='text-center pt-4'>Eliana</h2>
                  <p className='text-center'>Eliana is a new member of the team, she loves Tenerife and swimming with rays across the rocks.</p>
                  <span className="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg mx-auto w-100 d-block mb-3" onClick={handleElianaShow}>SEE&nbsp;MORE</span>
                  <Modal
                    show={elianaModal}
                    onHide={handleElianaClose}
                    keyboard={false}
                  >
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                      <Modal.Title><h2 className='mt-3'>Eliana bio</h2></Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                      Meet Eliana, a valuable member of the Scuba Point diving team based in Tenerife.
                    
                    </Modal.Body>
                  </Modal>
                </div>
              </Row>
            </Container>
          </div>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div >
  )
}

export default About
```