# React - the right way to show data using multiple react-bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

In an effort to learn **React.js** I created a simple app to display the personal data of all employees, using `react-bootstrap`. But there was a problem with `Modal` and I haven't found a solution. The problem is the data that appears for all `Modal` is the last employee data, in this case `employee-03`.

Take a peek at the code here (not the full code),
https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-wave-cjdo3

Based on this article,
[React-Bootstrap Multiple Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35060594/react-bootstrap-multiple-modal)
I suspect it seems that all `Modal` uses the same ID. What I'm confused about is how to set a different ID for each `Modal` if employee data will later be retrieved from a JSON file?

Thanks.

Regards, Erol.

Comment: i think it open the 3 modal each time .

Comment: try to save the index of the clicked button, and with this index pass the good data to the modal. and put the modal before map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same state to toggle all of the modals. If you play with the developer tools from React, you can see that every modal has it's corresponding data. 
I would create an array of booleans in the state or a **string with an id**:

```
  const [modalId, setModalId] = React.useState("");
  const handleClose = () => setModalId("");

  return (
    <Row className="App">
      {data.map((pax, i) => (
        <Col xs={12} md={4} key={pax.Uniquename}>
          <Card>
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title as="h4">{pax.Uniquename}</Card.Title>
              <Button type="button" onClick={() => setModalId(`modal${i}`)}>
                Open Modal
              </Button>
            </Card.Body>
            <Modal
              show={modalId === `modal${i}`}
              onHide={handleClose}
              aria-labelledby={`${pax.Uniquename}ModalLabel`}
              centered
            >
              <Modal.Header id={`${pax.Uniquename}ModalLabel`} closeButton>
                {pax.Uniquename}
              </Modal.Header>
              <Modal.Body>Full Name: {pax.Name}</Modal.Body>
            </Modal>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      ))}
    </Row>
  );
```

PS: It's just an example, you can re think your system.