# React-Bootsrap Multiple Modals

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a navbar with the usual login and sign-up buttons. When I click the relevant link, a modal with the form should pop-up allowing the user to login or sign-up. At the moment, neither of the pop-ups seem to work. I have been following [React-Bootstrap Multiple Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35060594/react-bootstrap-multiple-modal) and have been using the chosen answer to try and implement the modals.

The handle functions are in my app.jsx:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'
import {SessionProvider, useSession} from 'next-auth/react'
import {SSRProvider} from 'react-bootstrap'
import 'application.css';
import Navigation from "../components/Navigation";
import Login from "../components/Login";
import SideNav from "../components/SideNav";
import SignUp from "../components/SignUp";


function MyApp({Component, pageProps}) {
    let id = '';
    const [show, setShow] = useState(null)
    function handleClose() {
        setShow({show: id});
    }

    function handleShow(id) {
        setShow({show: id});
    }
    const [showSideBar, setShowSideBar] = useState(false)
    const toggleSideMenu = () => setShowSideBar((prev) => !prev);


    return (
        <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
            <SSRProvider>
                <SideNav showSideBar={showSideBar} />
                <Navigation
                  handleShow={handleShow}
                  handleClose={handleClose}
                  toggleSideMenu={toggleSideMenu}
                />

                <Login
                  show={show}
                  handleShow={handleShow}
                  handleClose={handleClose}
                />

                <SignUp
                  show={show}
                  handleShow={handleShow}
                  handleClose={handleClose}
                />

                {Component.auth
                    ? <Auth><Component {...pageProps} /></Auth>
                    : <Component {...pageProps} />
                }
            </SSRProvider>
        </SessionProvider>
    )
}

function Auth({children}) {
    // @ts-ignore
    const [session, loading] = useSession()
    const isUser = !!session?.user
    const router = useRouter()

    useEffect(() => {
        if (loading) return // Do nothing while loading
        if (!isUser) router.push('/login')
        // If not authenticated, force log in
    }, [isUser, loading])

    if (isUser) {
        return children
    }

    // Session is being fetched, or no user.
    // If no user, useEffect() will redirect.
    return <div>Loading...</div>
}

export default MyApp
```

I pass the show, handleshow, handleclose to each component. In the navigation the buttons look like this:

```
<Nav.Link href="#" onClick={() => handleShow('login')}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={solid('sign-in-alt')}/><span>&nbsp;Login</span></Nav.Link>
<Nav.Link href="#" onClick={() => handleShow('signup')}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={solid('user-plus')}/><span>&nbsp;Sign up</span></Nav.Link>
```

And then finally, my Login.jsx with a modal:

```
import {getCsrfToken, signIn, useSession} from "next-auth/react";
import Router from "next/router";
import { Modal, CloseButton, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Link from "next/link";
import { useState } from "react";

function Login({csrfToken, show, handleClose, handleShow, props}) {
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  //setShow(prev => !prev);


  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const res = await signIn('credentials', {
      redirect: false,
      email: e.target.email1.value,
      password: e.target.password1.value,
      callbackUrl: `/dashboard`,
    });

    if (res?.error) {
      setError(true);
    } else {
      Router.push('/dashboard');
    }

  }

  return (
    <Modal show={show === "login"} onHide={handleClose} fade={false}>
      <Modal.Header className={"modal-dark bg-dark"}>
        <Modal.Title><h1>Log In</h1></Modal.Title>
        <CloseButton variant="white" onClick={handleClose}/>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body className={"modal-dark bg-dark"}>
        <form noValidate onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
          <input name="csrfToken" type="hidden" defaultValue={csrfToken}/>
          <Form.Group className="mt-3">
            <Form.Control
              id="email-address1"
              name="email1"
              type="email"
              autoComplete="email"
              required
              className=""
              placeholder="Email address"
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group className="mt-3">
            <Form.Control
              id="password1"
              name="password1"
              type="password"
              autoComplete="current-password"
              required
              placeholder="Password"
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <button type={"submit"} className={"btn orange-button mt-3"}>Login</button>

          <div>
            or <Link href='/signup'>sign up</Link>
          </div>

          {error && <div className="bg-red-300 p-2 text-white rounded">Wrong email or password</div>}

        </form>

      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer className={"modal-dark bg-dark"}>
        <button onClick={handleClose}>
          Close
        </button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

In the developer tools looking at the React components tab, it is sending the correct information.

[image: React components tab]

The props all seem to be there, the modal just doesn't seem to pop-up. Thanks

Comment: show={show === "login"} seems incorrect as you are passing show as object {show: id} Try show.show === 'login'

Comment: @VishalRajole that just gives me TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'show')

Comment: because it's initially null. try adding safe check show?.show === 'login'

Comment: @VishalRajole Login works, but sign-up doesn't for some reason, so i'm halfway there. Thanks!