# bootstrap modal with z-index css

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, z-index

I am creating a web app in which i want to select date from textbox which is located at modal, when i click on the textbox date(material designing) is appearing behind the modal, i know it is because i need to set the z-index

the following examples are tried by me but i am unsuccessful

```
<style>
    .modal{
        position:relative;
        z-index:1;
}
    .calsen{
        position:absolute;
        z-index:1;
}
</style>
```

modal is not opening

```
<style>
    .modal{
        position:absolute;
        z-index:1;
}
    .calsen{
        position:absolute;
        z-index:2;
}
</style>
```

content behind the modal is appearing

```
<style>
    .modal{
        position:absolute;
        z-index:10000;
}
    .calsen{
        position:absolute;
        z-index:100000;
}
</style>
```

date is not appearing behind the modal and style of my modal function innappropriateky

```
<style>
    .modal{
        position:fixed;
        z-index:1;
}
    .calsen{
        position:absolute;
        z-index:100000;
}
</style>
```

content behind the modal is appearing

this is how i declare modal and textbox(inside modal body)

```
<div id="update" class="modal fade" role="dialog" >
```

Textbox

```
<div class="form-clearify">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:3px;">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="background-color:whitesmoke;">
            <label>Select Date </label>
            <md-datepicker class="calsen" ng-model="mddate" ng-change="dateformatechanged()" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

what i need to do now?

Comment: pls, provide a link to jsFiddle. nobody will gather your lego together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the z-index of your datepicker higher, instead of messing around with modal z-index. (Which could possibly break something else)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71031151/7186739

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

CSS:

```
.md-datepicker-calendar-pane {
  z-index: 1200;
}
```