# How to close multi modal forms right with the "Esc" keyboard button?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, jquery-events

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305821/multiple-modals-overlay#24914782) about how to avoid the overlay of the second modal. So I have applied the @A1rPun fix:

```js
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    var zIndex = 1040 + (10 * $('.modal:visible').length);
    $(this).css('z-index', zIndex);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.modal-backdrop').not('.modal-stack').css('z-index', zIndex - 1).addClass('modal-stack');
    }, 0);
});

$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    $('.modal:visible').length && $(document.body).addClass('modal-open');
});
```

Now when I press the `Esc` button the modal form in the back is closed. However, the form ahead is the one that must be closed.

I have tried to fix it by adding some listener like the below code. But if I do this, sometimes both forms are closed at the same time. Maybe because there is another listener already.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).keydown(function(event){
        if (event.keyCode == 27) {  // Esc code
            if ($('.modal-form').length > 0) {
                let z = 0;
                let modal_to_close = null;
                $('.modal-form').each(function () {
                    let current_z = parseInt($(this).css('z-index'), 10);
                    if (z < current_z) {
                        z = current_z;
                        modal_to_close = $(this);
                    }
                })
                modal_to_close.find('.close').click();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

How can I make this work well? Should I override the Bootstrap keydown listeners? How to do it?

[image]

**Note**: I am using Bootstrap v3.3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `tabindex="-1"` on your all modal, for example.

`<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1">`

<kbd>[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CxdUQ/1147/)</kbd>

Comment: When I press `Esc` in the front modal form then I need to click on the form that´s in the back to close it with `Esc` again. But it is enough for me, good approach