# How to add next button to popup?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to apply below script to create the next button on a popup. When I used the code to open the popup, it works properly. But when trying to apply the code to create the next button, it does not work. Please help me to fix the issue.

Here the script I used.

```
<script>       
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".getAssignment").click(function() {
      var $divs = $(this).parent().find(".modalDialog");
      if ($divs.length > 0) {
         window.location.href = "#" + $divs[ Math.floor(Math.random() * $divs.length) ].id;
      }
   });
});    
</script> 

<input class="getAssignment" type="button" value="Open Modal">

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
    <input class="getAssignment" type="button" value="Next">    
   <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
   <h2>Modal Box</h2>
        <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
        <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Sanjeewani/0pfov2b9/6/

Comment: How did you try to add button?

Comment: @Sanju, add a working Snippet.

Comment: the snippet does not work

Comment: here is the full code I tried. Actually, I want to open popups one by one using the next button. https://jsfiddle.net/Sanjeewani/0pfov2b9/2/

Comment: have you any idea? please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple modals overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305821/multiple-modals-overlay)

Comment: I want to open random popups. So I think it is not possible for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is  `var $divs = $(this).parent().find(".modalDialog");` it's correct relative the "Open Modal"-button, but from the "Next"-button inside the modal dialog `parent()` is not the element containing the modal-divs... try changing to `var $divs = $(".modalDialog");`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by getting a random div number.I have change js code little bit kindly check

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sr_num = ['1', '2', '3']; 
  $(".getAssignment").click(function() {
    var rand = sr_num[Math.floor(Math.random() * sr_num.length)];
    var demo = "#openModal" + rand;
    window.location.href.split('#')[0]
    window.location.href = demo;
  });
});
```

Here is working code [check here](https://jsfiddle.net/0pfov2b9/47/)

Hope it will help you

Comment: Happy to help :)