# Is there any chance to get different multiple popup modals with single modal code from different button click events

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, popup, bootstrap-modal, popupwindow

- I am using the bootstrap modal in my application.
- I have created 2 buttons when click button-one am able to get popup.
- I have tried change with z-index for overlay div, this helped for able to click button-2, i can seen in console log i have found 2 button clicks log messages..
- sample demo **[Modal stackblitz Demo](https://angular-ixuo7n.stackblitz.io)**
- I need to open popup-2 when click on button-2 with out closing the popup-1..

Edited: i need to click forendbackground page and popup modal page with multiple..

Comment: please provide code

Comment: -Please check this URL **[Editor Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pjjuax)**

Comment: how to find your modal after button click which one is open because some function is use for both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple modals overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305821/multiple-modals-overlay)