# How any modals can I stack in a single webpage?

Tags: html, database, bootstrap-modal

How many modals can I stack on top of each other? Can I pass data from one modal to another in this stack, like passing a value from modal #3 to modal #1? Can they all communicate with the database?

Tried Google already, didn't work. Yes, I know you're not supposed to stack modals, but I got up to a stack of five modals on top of one another and I've yet to crash. I'm interested in knowing the limits.

Comment: There are no limits. Stack as many modals as you would like :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305821/multiple-modals-overlay

Comment: Thanks, but can I pass data between them? The linked question contained too many variables and discussions unrelated to this, but thank you all the same.